# Capitalizing the First Character in a String in R

Tags: r, function, format

I want to capitalize the first name last name in a data frame.
Specifically, capitalize the first character in both first and last name and decapitalize the other characters in the name. However, the function I write does not give my the intended result.

```r
# Create a data frame of First Names
First.Name <- c("John", "MARY", "tommy", "DI", "leonardo")
firstname_df <- data.frame(FirstName)

# Write a function to format the names in a list
CapStr <- function(y) {
  for (i in 1:length(y)) {
    c <- strsplit(y[i], " ")[[1]]
    paste(toupper(substring(c, 1, 1)), tolower(substring(c, 2)), sep = "")
  }
}

# Call the function 
CapStr(First.Name)
# Show results
First.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = function(x){
    paste(toupper(substring(x, 1, 1)),
          tolower(substring(x, 2, nchar(x))),
          sep = "")
}

foo(First.Name)
#[1] "John"     "Mary"     "Tommy"    "Di"       "Leonardo"
```

Or use `regex`

```
gsub("(\\D)(\\D+)", "\\U\\1\\L\\2", First.Name, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "John"     "Mary"     "Tommy"    "Di"       "Leonardo"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tools::toTitleCase(tolower(First.Name))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're attempting to work from the `.simpleCap` function described in the documentation for `?tolower`:

```
.simpleCap <- function(x) {
    s <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
    paste(toupper(substring(s, 1, 1)), substring(s, 2),
          sep = "", collapse = " ")
}
```

which can be used to convert to upper case the first letter of every word in a single string. You've added a `for` loop and `tolower` on the remainder of the word. A better option might be to keep the `tolower`, but remove the `for` loop and instead use `sapply`:

```
CapStr <- function(y) {
    c <- strsplit(y, " ")[[1]]
    paste(toupper(substring(c, 1, 1)), tolower(substring(c, 2)), sep = "")
}

> sapply(First.Name,CapStr,USE.NAMES = F)
[1] "John"     "Mary"     "Tommy"    "Di"       "Leonardo"
```

Another option is to use `stringr::str_to_title`:

```
library(stringr)
> str_to_title(First.Name)
[1] "John"     "Mary"     "Tommy"    "Di"       "Leonardo"
```